# Change this nested loop program to list comprehension

Tags: python, algorithm, list-comprehension

Can you do this whole program using list comprehension?
Please share code.

```
c = [".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."]

transformations = []
for i in words:
    s = ""
    for j in i:
        s+=c[ord(j)-97]
    transformations.append(s)
return len(set(transformations))
```

Comment: The program written as is isn't working (`return` outside function, what is inside `words`? etc...)

Comment: What are you looking for? just replace `return` with `print` and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for:

```
words = ['Hello', 'world']

transformations = [''.join(c[ord(j.lower())-97] for j in i) for i in words]
```

Output:

```
>>> transformations
['......-...-..---', '.-----.-..-..-..']
#       Hello              world
```

Comment: Might even map that `list` into a `dict` to make the lookup a bit nicer. `c[j.lower()]` vs. `c[ord(j.lower())-97]`

Comment: I'm agree especially because `c` only contains letters (length: 26).  Missing numbers and punctuation. [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code)